# java.io.IOException: broken file descriptor

Tags: java, android, image, android-layout, layout

I try to get take a photo (from camera)

with the following code where

`imageCaptureUri = 
file:///storage/emulated/0/myApp/ProfileImageCapture.tmp`

`imageFile` is the output file == `/storage/emulated/0/myApp/ProfileImage.tmp`

```
  private void cropImage(Uri imageCaptureUri) {
    // Use existing crop activity.
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setDataAndType(imageCaptureUri, AccountSignInDetails.IMAGE_UNSPECIFIED);

    // Specify the output path
    File imageFile =
        new File(ResManager.mAppDir, AccountSignInDetails.PROFILE_IMAGE_FILE);
    intent.putExtra("output", Uri.fromFile(imageFile));

    // Specify image size
    intent.putExtra("outputX", 100);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", 100);

    // Specify aspect ratio, 1:1
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    intent.putExtra("scale", true);
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    // REQUEST_CODE_CROP_PHOTO is an integer tag you defined to
    // identify the activity in onActivityResult() when it returns
    mActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, ImageTaker.REQUEST_CODE_CROP_PHOTO);
  }
```

but **sometimes** I get the following log-cat error:

I understand that error is for the imageCaptureUri

```
05-11 11:26:19.338: W/DecodeUtils(24836): java.io.IOException: broken file descriptor
05-11 11:26:19.338: W/DecodeUtils(24836):   at android.graphics.BitmapRegionDecoder.nativeNewInstance(Native Method)
05-11 11:26:19.338: W/DecodeUtils(24836):   at android.graphics.BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(BitmapRegionDecoder.java:88)
05-11 11:26:19.338: W/DecodeUtils(24836):   at com.android.gallery3d.data.DecodeUtils.createBitmapRegionDecoder(DecodeUtils.java:229)
05-11 11:26:19.338: W/DecodeUtils(24836):   at com.android.gallery3d.data.UriImage$RegionDecoderJob.run(UriImage.java:175)
05-11 11:26:19.338: W/DecodeUtils(24836):   at com.android.gallery3d.data.UriImage$RegionDecoderJob.run(UriImage.java:171)
05-11 11:26:19.338: W/DecodeUtils(24836):   at com.android.gallery3d.app.CropImage$LoadDataTask.run(CropImage.java:1023)
05-11 11:26:19.338: W/DecodeUtils(24836):   at com.android.gallery3d.app.CropImage$LoadDataTask.run(CropImage.java:1014)
05-11 11:26:19.338: W/DecodeUtils(24836):   at com.android.gallery3d.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:133)
05-11 11:26:19.338: W/DecodeUtils(24836):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-11 11:26:19.338: W/DecodeUtils(24836):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-11 11:26:19.338: W/DecodeUtils(24836):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-11 11:26:19.338: W/DecodeUtils(24836):   at com.android.gallery3d.util.PriorityThreadFactory$1.run(PriorityThreadFactory.java:44)
```

how can i fix the broken uri ?

Comment: And what is the full path for the  output file?

Comment: you mean `imageFile`? this is the output file == /storage/emulated/0/myApp/ProfileImage.tmp

Comment: So there are two files involved. For which one would there be a broken file descriptor?

Comment: **sometimes** I get the following log-cat error:

I understand that error is for the imageCaptureUri

Comment: how can i be sure which is the broken uri?

Comment: Don't know. That's for you to find out ;-). Cannot imageCaptureUri without file://?